# Do problems from competitive exams for colleges count as "Competition Maths"?

Tags: support, contests

I recently came across this post [on always mentioning if a question is from a competition](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/32403/879009)

, and in the past, I've asked many questions that are from certain comeptitive exams in my country. However, these exams aren't explicitly for maths, so I'm not sure if I should have used that tag in the past, and moreover, what should I do in the future. Do I include the "competitive-maths" tag or not?

Comment: I suppose you have the [tag:contest-math] tag in mind?  It would make sense to specifically identify the source of the problems, whether or not that tag is used.  Tags serve mainly for searching/filtering, and do not replace the necessary problem formulation/context in the body of a Question.  However you can use the tag if it seems appropriate in your view.

Comment: I will do that in the future. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Yes, your question is a contest question because it is from a contest.

Even if the contest is not explicitly about math, it is still a contest problem. You still need to disclose the source, explain that this is a general academic contest (or whatever the correct description is), and follow the rest of the advice on how to ask a good question.

Comment: I don't follow... Are exams and contests synonymous?

Comment: @TheAmplitwist School exams are not. Competitive exams which span a city/district or greater region, are.

Comment: @insipidintegrator [Some school exams](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Board_examination) are conducted at the national level. In any case, this is the first time I've seen someone use "contest" and "competitive exam" synonymously, and it's really not clear to me how/why.

Answer (score -3):

## No it's not a contest question

Firstly if your competitive exams are anything like the ones in my country then the exams are conducted offline and the same questions are not repeated between papers which batches of students write.

So, there is no particular gain or loss in knowing the answer to the question **once the exam is over** in relation to the exam conducted.

Nonetheless, I would advise writing relevant information like which exact exam paper you got the question from. This is useful because if one person liked the question and want to see more like it, then they would know where to go , or, maybe they think a mistake is there in the question and want to check if you have written the question correctly.

Best of luck.

Comment: I disagree with your very large bolded bit: it's a question from a contest!

Comment: will do, @tryst with freedom. Thanks!